# Why is \Pr not defined using \nolimits?

Tags: math-mode

Plain TeX defines `\Pr` as

```
\def\Pr{\mathop{\rm Pr}}
```

LaTeX and ConTeXt define it similarly (with some syntax sugar around the choice of the font). To me, a more reasonable definition is

```
\def\Pr{\mathop{\rm Pr}\nolimits}
```

so that constructs like `\Pr^{f}(X)` look nice.

Are there any scenarios where the tradition TeX definition is more appropriate than the latter?

Answer (score 4):

I can't speak to the design decisions made in plain TeX, LaTeX, ConTeXt, or `amsmath` (which reimplements `\Pr`). My guess is the reason it doesn't have `\nolimits` is because it is common to see `\Pr_x` denoting the probability over the choice of *x*.

I agree that `\Pr^f(X)` looks quite strange with the normal definitions.

Comment: To me even `\Pr_X` looks better with `\nolimits`. Are their branches of math/comp sci where authors use `\Pr_X` with the default definition of `\Pr`?

Comment: @Aditya: I'm not a mathematician (I just play one on the internet).  I'm positive that I've seen it in computer science papers. But then, those are almost universally written in LaTeX so it seems reasonable to assume that people don't change the definitions. The concentration of measure book sitting on my desk has the `\nolimits` version. The information theory book on my desk doesn't seem to have any subscripts for `\Pr`. It seems like it's becoming more common to use `\mathbb P` instead of `\Pr`. I've never seen `\mathop{\mathbb P}\limits_X` though.

Comment: Thanks TH. I also see `\mathbb P` or `mathds P` (from `dsfont` package) more often, and always with `\nolimits`.