# ConTeXt: bar over and under integral symbol

Tags: context, math-operators, context-mkiv

I use ConTeXT and I want to put bars over and under the integral sign.

For LaTeX, there is a [similar question here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/211101/52406), and I think that [the answer given by egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/211132/52406) looks indeed very nice (see image below).

Question: How to do this in ConTeXt? The result should look like this:

[image: egregs result]

Below is a very naive try from my side, based on the comment by @Manuel (it is not Manuel's fault that it does not work, but mine!) but that does not compile. Since I don't understand the code, there is probably something simple I forgot (I changed the name `\tb@int` to `\tbint`, maybe that is a no-no). My hope is that, with the code, someone will easily spot what is wrong and be able to correct.

```
\def\tint{\mathop{\mathpalette\tbint{t}}\!\int}
\def\bint{\mathop{\mathpalette\tbint{b}}\!\int}
\def\tbint#1#2{%
  \sbox\zeropoint{$\mathsurround\zeropoint#1\int$}%
  \if#2t%
    \rlap{\hbox to\wd\zeropoint{%
      \hfil
      \vrule width .35em height \dimexpr\ht\zeropoint+1.4pt\relax depth -\dimexpr\ht\zeropoint+1pt\relax
      \kern.05em % a small correction on the top
    }}
  \else
    \rlap{\hbox to\wd\zeropoint{%
      \vrule width .35em height -\dimexpr\dp\zeropoint+1pt\relax depth \dimexpr\dp\zeropoint+1.4pt\relax
      \hfil
    }}
  \fi
}

\starttext
\startformula
\tint_a^b f(x)\,dx \bint_a^b f(x)\,dx.
\stopformula
\stoptext
```

Finally, to avoid the "obvious" answer: using `\overline{\int}` and `\underline{\int}` does not look good enough.

Comment: `\m@th` = `\mathsurround\zeropoint`, `\z@` = `\zeropoint`. I think that's enough, altough may be it's better to use conventions of ConTeXt that I'm not aware of.

Comment: @Manuel Thank you, that helps a bit in the understanding the code.

Comment: There are two mistakes. First, `\sbox` in ConTeXt is something completely different from `\sbox` in LaTeX. Second, saying `\sbox\z@` in LaTeX is equivalent to `\setbox0` (i.e., box 0, which is used as a scratchbox in LaTeX); you translated it to `\zeropoint` which is not a box. Usually, ConTeXt uses `\scratchbox` for such calculations (rather than relying on the number of the box)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an almost literal translation of egreg's answer. I have just changed the coding style to match the usual coding style used in ConTeXt:

```
\unprotect
\define\tint{\mathop{\mathpalette\tb@int{t}}\!\int}
\define\bint{\mathop{\mathpalette\tb@int{b}}\!\int}
\define[2]\tb@int
 {\setbox\scratchbox\hbox{$\mathsurround\zeropoint#1\int$}%
  \if#2t%
    \rlap{\hbox to \wd\scratchbox
      {\hfil
      \vrule width .35em height \dimexpr\ht\scratchbox+1.4pt\relax depth -\dimexpr\ht\scratchbox+1pt\relax
      \kern.05em % a small correction on the top
    }}
  \else
    \rlap{\hbox to\wd\scratchbox
      {\vrule width .35em height -\dimexpr\dp\scratchbox+1pt\relax depth \dimexpr\dp\scratchbox+1.4pt\relax
      \hfil
    }}
  \fi
}
\protect

\starttext
\startformula
\tint_a^b f(t)\,dt=\bint_a^b f(t)\,dt
\textstyle
\tint_a^b f(t)\,dt=\bint_a^b f(t)\,dt
\stopformula
\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Aditya! This solves my problem completely. The output you show me also reminds of wondering why`\setupmathematics[integral=nolimit]` is not the default setting. Coming from Mathematics, I really think it should be. Anyways, thanks again for a good answer!

Comment: In ConTeXt, the default in almost all cases is _do nothing_. That is the reason, there is almost no styling of section headings, no default value for parskip, no default value of indentation, etc. The idea is that a user needs to actively decide all parts of the document design. With math, one could envision a module with sensible defaults.

Comment: I understand the philosophy, and I like it, but I thought that "do nothing" here was to leave the limits "to the right" of the integral sign, and not above. I guess they are "to the right" if you write in plain TeX (not that plain TeX has to be what one compares with) without changing any setting.

Comment: To place the limits on the right, `\int` has to be defined as `\mathop{\intop}\nolimits`. To do nothing, it has to be defined as `\mathop{\intop}`. So, the current behavior is the default behavior of `\mathop`.

Comment: I see. Now I have more respect for that default choice (but still do not agree with it). Since I use the same setting in all files, it might be a good idea to put it in a module. Thanks again, and sorry for discussing off topic stuff in the comments to your answer.

Comment: No need to apologize. I don't like the default choice made in ConTeXt. But I understand why it is done that way. Even some of the default choices of plain TeX and amsmath don't make sense: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3590/323